# array of dictionaries / How to update a value on a specific key and index?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an array of dictionaries and it is saved in app's documents directory
How to update a value on a specific key and index?
Ex: I want to update the second Dictionary person's name

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
      <dict>
            <key>personName</key>
            <string>John Sculey</string>
            <key>isPersonAdult</key>
            <true/>
            <key>personID</key>
            <integer>12541</integer>
            <key>personPicture</key>
            <string>john.jpg</string>
            <key>personDesignation</key>
            <string>Branding Manager</string>
            <key>personDepartment</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <key>personEmail</key>
            <string>john@johnsculey.com</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
           <key>personName</key>
            <string>Chris Seattle</string>
            <key>isPersonAdult</key>
            <true/>
            <key>personID</key>
            <integer>89854</integer>
            <key>personPicture</key>
            <string>chris.jpg</string>
            <key>personDesignation</key>
            <string>Branding Manager</string>
            <key>personDepartment</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <key>personEmail</key>
            <string>chris@johnsculey.com</string>
    </dict>
```

and so on....

Comment: Isn't `[[array objectAtIndex:1] setObject:@"New Name" forKey:@"personName"];` good enough?

Comment: Yes it is good enough :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

So, **assuming your dictionary is mutable,**

```
[[array objectAtIndex:1] setObject:@"New Name" forKey:@"personName"];
```

(If it isn't, create a mutable copy of it beforehands.)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if I get your question correct. But if you are asking, how you can access the dictionary at a specific index of an array, this would be the way:

```
NSMutableDictionary *person = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[array objectAtIndex:1]];
[person setValue:@"Chris Washington" forKey:@"personName"];
```

It doesn't matter, what kind of objects the array holds; it can be numbers or - as in your case - dictionary objects. You access them as normal.

Answer (score 0):

my 2 cents too :D

```
id data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:plistFile];
NSArray *plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:data options:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:nil error:nil];
assert([plist isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]);

//every element in the array is mutable
NSMutableDictionary *dict = plist[1];
dict[@"key"] = @"value";
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do what you want with a few lines of code... First you get the dictionary you want to edit from the array, and then you change the value for your key. I haven't tested this code but it should work well!

```
NSURL *documents = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSURL *plistUrl = [documents URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourPlistName.plist"];
NSArray *plistContents = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:plistUrl];
NSMutableDictionary *personToEdit = [plistContents objectAtIndex:1];
[personToEdit setValue:@"value you want to set" forKey:@"your key"];
```

Comment: Yes but I assumed it was a mutable dictionary, I only typed wrong because I'm answering from an iPad and it isn't so confortable... Sorry for that!